# Speech Language is not downloading

Tags: 8.0, settings, lumia

I have changed my speech language to new one, and it showing ***Downloading*** all the time.

[image: Via System > Speech > Speech Language]

It has been still *Downloading* for 2 weeks (It's only 24Mb, expected to finish within a minute). I have connected to a high speed WiFi. And I can't cancel or can't download any other language right now. Any answer other than hard reset will be appreciated.

Comment: as assume you have restarted your phone? did you do a soft-reset?

Comment: yes, i did number of times.

Comment: having the same problem here with my nokia lumia 720

Comment: Is your phone up to date? Any phone updates apart from Spech downloads that are pending?

Comment: Yes, it's. I do phone updates, application updates etc. as when they are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following was helpful for me, you can try it.

"Goto settings > language+region. If you have set your country to UK, and language set to Spanish at the moment, then try temporarily either change country to Spain and leave language as Spanish or Leave the country as UK and set language to English."

Comment: It's a good solution. And please remove the other answer (it's not an answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and rebooting did not work. The download always got stuck and nothing seemed to be happening.

I then went to "phone update" and asked it to check for updates. It immediately told me new updates were being downloaded, then installed and asked to reboot so my language pack would be updated.

It seems downloading from the "speech" screen will only mark it as needed, but not actually trigger the action. Going to "phone update" and explicitly asking it to check for updates did the trick.

I'm using a Nokia Lumia 925.